# Wait For Seconds Stopping Symptoms(Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void Start() 
{ 
    DataController.GetInstance().LoadItemButton(this); 
    StartCoroutine("AddMoneyLoop"); 
    UpdateUI();
}

IEnumerator AddMoneyLoop()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(isPurchased)
        {
            DataController.GetInstance().AddMoney(moneyPerSec);
        }
        //Thread.Sleep(2000);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
    }
}
```

I did the coding with the above code.
I want AddMoney to loop every second.
But it stops after 3~6 times of repetition.

yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);

I think the code above is the problem. How do you solve it?

Comment: Is the GameObject this coroutine is running on disabled or destroyed? Otherwise what exactly means `it stops`? Getting any error? So you somewhere change the `Time.timeScale`? Without further information/code it is not possible to give an answer here ...

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the rest of your code, it's likely it's getting garbage collected. You should root it by assigning it to a field in your class when you start it.

Comment: private void Start()
    {
        DataController.GetInstance().LoadItemButton(this);

        StartCoroutine("AddMoneyLoop");

        UpdateUI();
    }

The code above is written.

Comment: Oh, if Unity is instantiating it by name then you're out of luck, you can't do anything about it.

Comment: You're saying there's no solution?

Comment: Nothing is impossibe, it just depends on your code (not random small snippets, your entire code). For example a quick Google search gave this: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1259637/coroutine-gets-gcd-when-owner-object-is-garbage-co.html

Comment: @Blindly this isn't really related to GC .. the `IEnumerator` you see is running as a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) .. without further information/code it is not possible to give an answer here

Comment: It doesn't matter what you call it, coroutine or pink puppy, it's an enumerator that is instantiated with a call to `GetEnumerator()` and iterated using basic `MoveNext()` and `Current`. As a disposable object, it follows normal GC rules.